# css menu remains open in iPad

Tags: css, ipad

I have a css menu, which opens a submenu onclick. The problem is when a submenu is selected it open the page, but the menu doesn't get hidden. It remains open until we click anywhere on the iPad screen.

**CSS**

```
.menuDiv:hover>.submenuDropdown, .menuDiv:focus>.submenuDropdown {
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
}

.submenuDropdown {
background: #fff;
position: absolute;
width: auto;
min-width: 250px;   
list-style:none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="menuDiv">
<ul class="submenuDropdown">
<li>Link 1</li>
<li>Link 2</li>
<li>Link 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The submenuDropdown ul always remain open.

Comment: use `:hover` instead of `:focus`

Comment: Are you preparing a website optimized for iPad? Or a web app?